# Block or redirect website page URLs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having some issues with spam links visiting my site returning a 404 error.

My site was hacked with a secret spam links folder on public_html that redirected users to pornographic sites, those links were plastered across the internet. I have since remedied the malware issue, but have several hundred visitors hitting a 404 page because these links no longer exist, messing up all my analytics accounts, using bandwidth, etc.

I have searched for a way to block (so that they never hit my website) anyone that tries to access these URL paths, but cannot possibly redirect every single link (there were over 2000) using a wildcard, or something. My search led me here: [Block Spam Referrer Traffic](http://www.codediesel.com/security/how-to-block-referrer-spam-traffic/) and it is not quite the solution I need.

The searches go to pages like this: `www.mywebsite.com/spampage/morespam/` (which have been deleted and are now 404 errors)

There are several iterations of the `/spampage/` and `/morespam/` urls.

The referrer is generally a google search, so I can't block the referrer using .htaccess. I'd like to somehow block `www.mywebsite.com/spampage/*/` and all iterations.

Apologies, I am by no means a programmer. I do appreciate any help that can be offered.

**Update#1:**

*Seems that perhaps the best way is to block these links/directories using the robots.txt file, I have done so and will report back if I have success!*

**Update#2:**

*Reporting back. I am new to this all, so I was going about the solution wrong in my original question. Essentially, I found that I needed all of the links de-indexed, as they were generating all the traffic by being indexed by google. I was able to request de-indexing of the directories in question manually through the google webmaster tools account. One requirement for de-indexing was to have the robots.txt on the site block the directories in question from being crawled. Once I did that I submitted the request to remove the directory from the google index. Those pages were taken off in about 3 hours by google (thanks google!), so it was pretty quick once I found out the proper way to go about it. No .htaccess editing needed. Once the pages were no longer index, traffic went back down to normal levels and my keywords, etc, will be back to normal.*

Comment: You can try sending a "410 Gone" instead of a "404 Not Found" for these URLs to get search engines/bots to drop them quicker? If you directed these requests to an alternative/lighter 404/410 document, would that be preferable?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was desperate, and found a solution. I blocked the pages from being indexed using the "robots.txt" file on my website. I didn't want to wait for Google to crawl and de-index the 2000, so I used my webmaster tools account to manually request deindexing of the 20 directories that had been created for spam. Google actually deindexed the pages within about 3 hours.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back; glad you got it sorted. A minor technical clarification... a robots.txt file doesn't actually block pages from being indexed; it blocks pages from being _crawled_. Pages can still be indexed if they are linked to and if they are already indexed; they are already indexed! But if the pages don't exist anyway, then there is nothing to index so the links would eventually drop out of the index (if they are not blocked by robots.txt!).

Comment: I see, thanks for the correction! I think it was a google policy that if you want pages deindexed you have to first block them using the robots.txt. I was getting tons of traffic from the fake links and it was throwing off all of my data (and just plain annoying porn spam link). So, the pages in question must have already been crawled and indexed. I am glad that I could fast-track getting them off of the google index for sure!  Thanks again!

Comment: You could add your "question edit" as an answer and mark it as accepted (which you can do for your own question) - that way it will take it out of the unanswered question queue.